# Can I download 3rd party songs on the iPad and add them to iTunes Match?

Tags: itunes, ipad, itunes-match

I wonder if i can buy and download songs e.g. via Bandcamp in Safari, and then add them to my iTunes match right on my iPad?

I know how to do that with iTunes on the Mac, but it would be neat to have this also on the iPad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. You won't be able to add the in iTunes and thus you won't be able to add them to iTunes match.